# how do i automatically fill in fields using data from another table (based on foreign key = primary key) in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Basically, I have a main client table with the primary key "Client_ID." Within this client table, there are other fields such as "Client_Name" and  "Phone_Number." And I have other tables such as quotation, where there is also the "Client_ID" field as the foreign key, referencing the primary key in the client table. Within the quotation table, there are also a few selected duplicate fields from the client table such as Client_Name again. I do this so I can make automatically generated quotation documents using fields from the quotation table. Anyhow, is there a way so that when I type in for example, "C-0001" in the foreign key client_id in the quotation table, there is no need to type in fields such as the Client_Name again, and instead corresponding data is copied over from the client table?

Comment: "... there are also a few selected duplicate fields from the client table such as Client_Name again..." -- that's redundancy. By definition redundancy is expensive to maintain, so there should be a compelling reason to have it, typically extreme performance. Are you sure you want redundancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with a trigger, but the more idiomatic approach would be to keep these fields in the `client` table only, and use a join to query them when you need to create a quotation report:

```sql
SELECT q.*, c.client_name, c.phone_number
FROM   quotation q
JOIN   client c ON q.client_id = c.client_id
```

Comment: could you please show me how it'd work with a trigger? i just really want to complete my project at this point, and i'd have to restructure everything if i went with the idiomatic approach.

Comment: wait nevermind, honestly that makes lots of sense, thank you.

Comment: hey! i know this was from awhile ago - but do you know if i can merge together fields from more than one table?

Comment: @georgie you can join in how many tables you need. Can you post a new question with all the relevant details and link it here? It would be easier than using comments.